# Text vertical-align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to set the vertical-align of the list to make it centered with the picture next to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="box">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <hr>
                 <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Čím se
                     <strong>zabýváme</strong>
                 </h2>
                 <hr>
                 <img class="img-responsive img-left thumbnail" src="img/intro-pic.jpg" alt="">
                 <hr class="visible-xs">
                 <ul class="list-unstyled intro-text">
                   <li>Rekonstrukce bytů, bytových a rodinných domů</li>
                   <li>Stavby rodinných domů</li>
                   <li>Zateplování fasád</li>
                   <li>Rekonstrukce koupelen</li>
                   <li>Zemní práce</li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .box {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding: 30px 15px;
     background: #fff;
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 }

 .intro-text {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 1em;
     font-weight: 400;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
```

Text is aligned on top of the picture now and It doesn't look nice because there is so much free space below it.

Comment: please exaplin further what you're looking for (since we can't see image it's hard to tell what you're looking to achieve.)

Comment: I can't insert images yet, but I made a screenshot for you. That is how I would like to align It :http://gyazo.com/232254feefd2bbb1fe6d41e2e7e660b9. @jbutler483

Comment: pls add the path of your image or some other image for ref.

Comment: http://90574.w74.wedos.ws/img/intro-pic.jpg @anji

Comment: @tomas nosek http://jsfiddle.net/zj9v81t7/25/ try this . all responsive image and vertically text aligned centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` on the image and `ul` and then align them vertically to the middle.

```css
.box img, .box ul {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <hr/>
             <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Čím se
                     <strong>zabýváme</strong>
                 </h2>

            <hr/>
            <img class="img-responsive img-left thumbnail" src="http://90574.w74.wedos.ws/img/intro-pic.jpg" alt="" />
            <ul class="list-unstyled intro-text">
                <li>Rekonstrukce bytů, bytových a rodinných domů</li>
                <li>Stavby rodinných domů</li>
                <li>Zateplování fasád</li>
                <li>Rekonstrukce koupelen</li>
                <li>Zemní práce</li>
            </ul>
            <hr class="visible-xs" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TomášNosek is the result in the code snippet what you want? If so, you must be doing something wrong to implement it. Can you recreate the issue in [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Note that I have changed the HTML slightly and moved the `<hr class="visible-xs" />` to **after** the `ul`

Comment: The result in the code snipper is exactly what I have been looking for. Nothing changes when I implement the code though.

Comment: Then you obvioulsy have something else affecting your code.

Comment: I am not able to find the mistake. Could you please try to? I have uploaded the whole webpage: http://90574.w74.wedos.ws/index.html. @Paulie_D

Comment: The image is floated in your `.img-left` class...remove the float.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using positioning for this. (although bootstrap wouldn't be the nicest of plugins to used IMHO):

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
.box {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   padding: 30px 15px;
   background: #fff;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 }
 .intro-text {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-weight: 400;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 .myWrap {
   position: relative;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   display:table;
 }
 #this {
   position: absolute;
   height:100%;
   top:0;
   right:-100%;
   width:80%;
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <hr>
      <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Čím se
                     <strong>zabýváme</strong>
                 </h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="myWrap">
        <img class="img-responsive img-left thumbnail" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" alt="">
        <hr class="visible-xs">
        <ul id="this" class="list-unstyled intro-text">
          <li>Rekonstrukce bytů, bytových a rodinných domů</li>
          <li>Stavby rodinných domů</li>
          <li>Zateplování fasád</li>
          <li>Rekonstrukce koupelen</li>
          <li>Zemní práce</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```